# add_term_meta não executa

Tags: wordpress

Preciso criar um term com o mesmo nome do post, pra isso estou usando a action save_post. O term é criado normalmente mas ao adicionar metadados a função add_term_meta não executa. Esse é o código.

```
function create_product_group($post_id){
  if(get_post_type($post_id) != 'product'){
    return;
  }

  $product_group = get_term_by( 'name', get_the_title($post_id) , 'product_group');

  if(!$product_group){
    $product_group_id = wp_insert_term( get_the_title($post_id) , 'product_group', array('description' => get_the_excerpt( $post_id )));

    add_term_meta($product_group_id,"book_group_author" , 'Elder Carvalho'); //adiciona autores
    add_term_meta($product_group_id,"book_group_image", 'http://teste.jpg'); //imagem do livro
    add_term_meta($product_group_id,"book_group_category", 'geral'); //categorias do livro

    $product_group = get_term_by('id', $product_group_id, 'product_group');
  }

  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $product_group->term_id , 'product_group');
}
add_action('save_post','create_product_group');
```

add_term_meta executa normalmente fora da função create_product_group.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) retorna um `array` contendo `term_id` e `term_taxonomy_id`, quando executada corretamente, então você deve passar o `term_id` às funções `add_term_meta` e `get_term_by`:

```
add_term_meta( $product_group_id['term_id'], "book_group_author" , 'Elder Carvalho' );

get_term_by( 'id', $product_group_id['term_id'], 'product_group' );
```

Comment: Exato Ricardo, obrigado pela ajuda.